# How To Read JsonData inside WebApi result using knockout js

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

I have returned Result.items using WebApi in those items one item is JsonData  how to read jsonData using Knockout.js of my MVC Application

I have tried as follows in a view

```
 <ul id="modelView" class="modelList" data-bind="foreach: modelItemList">
        <li class="modelListItem" style="border: solid" data-bind="css: { selected: $data == $root.selectedItem() }">
            <span data-bind="text: $data.ComponentName"></span>
            <ul>
                  <li class="modelList" data-bind="foreach: data.JsonData">
                    <span data-bind="text: data.ColumnName"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </li>
```

my modelItemList object as follows it is a list of DashBoardComponent

```
public class DashBoardComponent
{
    public int ComponentId { get; set; }
    public string ComponentName { get; set; }
    public string ComponentType { get; set; }
    public string JsonData { get; set; }
}
```

and my jsonData is list of object of DashBoardComponentColumn

```
public class DashBoardComponentColumn
{
    public int ColumnId { get; set; }
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public string ColumnType { get; set; }
}
```

then my problem how to read jsondata ,i'm trying as above but it results only one component.
How to read the data using knockout js

Answer (score 0):

It seems like JsonData is a string, not a list. As such, the .NET json serializer will not turn it into a json list. If json data is truly a list of anything, you should instantiate it as a List.

Comment: in this example what i have i done exactly is i deserialize the entire json data into list of columns and i prepare one view model as follows                                                         `public class DashBoardViewModel
    {
        public int ComponentId { get; set; }
        public string ComponentName { get; set; }
        public string ComponentType { get; set; }
        public List<DashBoardComponentColumn> columnlist { get; set; }
    }`                                                            and it return back to the view..